# C# PowerShell create blank text file on desktop

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm trying to use PowerShell from C# to create a new file on desktop. In the terminal you would do:

```
cd desktop
$null >> newfile.txt
```

So I'm trying to do this in C# to mimic the previous statements:

```
using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
{
  PowerShellInstance.AddScript("cd desktop; $null >> newfile.txt");

  PowerShellInstance.Invoke();
}
```

This runs without any exceptions but the file isn't created on the desktop. Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong with the `AddScript`?

**EDIT**

It looks like the problem comes from using cd and then the create in sequence.

I was able to get it working by doing

```
PowerShellInstance.AddScript("$null >> C:\\users\\me\\Desktop\\newfile.txt");
```

If anyone knows how to do a cd command followed by another please let me know.

Comment: Just to clarify: you specifically want to use PowerShell to do this? You don't want a C# File solution instead?

Comment: Yes I'm basically testing how to do things in PowerShell from C# since I'm later going to use it to run git commands.

Comment: @Nived Sorry, but I would never do that in the console (redirect `$null`) to create a new file. `New-Item $HOME\Desktop\newfile.txt`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen This is mostly just a test to see how to run commands in PowerShell from C#. The idea was just to figure out how to go to a specific directory and execute a command, the redirect was just a sample command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it looks like the command `cd desktop` itself is not working. If you open a powershell console then he default path it opens up in is `C:\Users\user_name\` and most probably from c# it's not opening with that path rather instead is opening with the working directory being the debug folder of your current project; [as commented by @Nived]

There is no issue with your current code. Just change the script statement to below and it should work fine

```
cd C:\Users\user_name\desktop; $null >> newfile.txt
```

With that your C# code should be something like

```
using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
 {
  PowerShellInstance.AddScript(@"cd C:\Users\user_name\desktop; $null >> newfile.txt");

 PowerShellInstance.Invoke();
}
```

Comment: It goes to the debug folder of your current project that you are executing from to start. So you have to specify the full path or use `~` to do it.

Comment: @Nived, good to know. You can edit my answer and include this piece of information if you would like.

Comment: In .NET you can also use stuff like `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory)` to get the full path of the folder where "Desktop" items are.

Comment: @Jeppe or in Powershell that's `[Environment]::GetFolderPath([Environment+SpecialFolder]::Desktop)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the environment variables to find the desktop as well.

```
using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
{
   PowerShellInstance.AddScript(@"cd (Join-Path (Join-Path $env:HOMEDRIVE $env:HOMEPATH) desktop); $null >> newfile.txt");

   PowerShellInstance.Invoke();
}
```